# How to tab a line in <code> segment?

Tags: support

**What i want?**

When i write a code sample in `{}` `<code>` segment i want to tab a line with use a specific keyword (like 'TAB').

Standart Code :

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
sayHello("Hello World");
}
```

Beauty Code :

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    sayHello("Hello World");
}
```

**Problem**

When i hit `TAB` or `Shift+TAB` stackoverflow change the textarea box in html.

**What i am doing?**

For tabbing a line in a code segment i am using `SPACE` *four* times and it so annoying for me?

**How can i solve this problem?**

Is there any specific keyword for tab a line in a code segment?

Comment: You solve this problem by typing code in an editor and just pasting it here. Alternatively, copy/paste four spaces, so you have an “indent key combination”.

Comment: I think stackoverflow gives us a specific key for this.

Comment: You can use Ctrl+K, but it will only indent the line *if it's not yet indented* (less than 3 spaces). If you try to indent it again by Ctrl+K, it will remove the indent instead.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> isn't implemented as indentation "key", in the SO editor. You're gonna have to manually add the indentation.
You don't need to press <kbd>Space</kbd> 4 times for each tab, though:

1. <kbd>Space</kbd> * 4
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
4. Repeat step 3 where necessary.

Or, if your code *isn't* indented yet:

1. Select it
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

This should properly indent your code.

Comment: Ctrl+K is enough but only my code isn't indented.